# 10x10 board on JS with divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild, createelement

Could someone help me how should I make a **board 10x10** using **divs** only on **JS** **with content**?
I made a board 10x10 with no problems, but I couldn't fill divs with content...
Code:

```
var hello = 100;
function createBoard() {
    // Height
    for(a=0; a<10; a++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(row);
        for(b=0; b<10; b++) {
            var column = document.createElement("div"); 
            column.innerHTML = 'hello';
            row.appendChild(column);
        }
    }
}
```

My code makes a 10x10 div table, in the sentence 9 ( `column.innerHTML = '100';` ) if I write instead of '100', hello - he will write *undefined*. But if I write it '100' he will write 100 times ( 10x10 ), 100. Why? How should I fix it?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but anyway, your `a` and `b` counters are missing a `let` or `var`. You're asking for trouble making these global.

Comment: @Lev Shapiro can you make a code snippet for us to understand your problem better?

Comment: Code works when `column.innerHTML = '100' `, but when it is `column.innerHTML = hello ` it will say undefined.

Comment: look at @dale edit he explained why that error occurred with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are initiating your variables in your loops. Lastly, if you are looking for a grid type layout, make the containing div a flexbox display.

EDIT: If you look closely at the order of operations in your code, you are calling your function AFTER you define your variable, hello.

Moreover, not so much related to the exact issue, but potentially a reason you were not able to see why you got the issue with your code, take note of the ***WAY*** you initialize the variable. You use `var`, var is a function scope and will throw an undefined where as `const` and `let` will throw errors...

```
#board {
  display: flex;
}
```

```js
function createBoard() {
    const hello = 100;
    for(let a=0; a<10; a++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(row);
        row.className = 'row';
        for(let b=0; b<10; b++) {
            var column = document.createElement("div"); 
            column.innerHTML = hello;
            column.className = 'column';
            row.appendChild(column);
    
        }
    }
    
}

createBoard()
```

```css
#board {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Order of operations changed... This will throw the undefined as the initialization of the variable is using the `var` type. replace this with `let` or `const` and you will get an error. The take off, use `let` and `const` over `var` unless you have a very specific reason for needing your variables definition to be able to be changed outside of block scope.

```js
createBoard()

var hello = 100;

function createBoard() {
    
    for(let a=0; a<10; a++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(row);
        row.className = 'row';
        for(let b=0; b<10; b++) {
            var column = document.createElement("div"); 
            column.innerHTML = hello;
            column.className = 'column';
            row.appendChild(column);
    
        }
    }
    
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Now lets change the initialization type to `let` and see what we get when order of operations is not correct.

```js
createBoard()

let hello = 100; // this will show an error using 'const' initialization as well

function createBoard() {
    
    for(let a=0; a<10; a++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(row);
        row.className = 'row';
        for(let b=0; b<10; b++) {
            var column = document.createElement("div"); 
            column.innerHTML = hello;
            column.className = 'column';
            row.appendChild(column);
    
        }
    }
    
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Note the error instead of undefined...
***"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'hello' before initialization"***

This error passing is precisely ***why*** you should stop using `var` and start using `let` or `const` unless you have a specific ***reason*** you want to pass function scope. Using `var` you get no clue as to why the code is not working, where as the newer form of variable initialization using `let` or `const` will throw potential errors to assist in your trouble shooting.

Comment: Oh thanks! I needed just to put the var inside the function, but I putted it before the function :)